What would an unleavened souffle be called?
It seems that an important part of a souffle is that it rises and becomes fluffy.  But it quickly collapses, and I find that the ingredients baked together taste just as good anyway, even without a leavening agent.  What would I call that dish?
It's got milk, eggs, butter, flour, sugar, spices, and pureed pumpkin or carrot, baked together.

It sounds a little like a frittata, but they often have potatoes, greens, cheese, bacon, etc and other things mixed in with the egg mixture. I've never seen a frittata with flour in it, or sugar for that matter. Search online for fritatta recipes, and see if that fits the bill.

"Unleavened souffle" "Weird omlette" "fallen souffle" "Flat souffle" "Egg Thing I Like"... Or you can get in on the "Smash" food naming trend with "Smashed Souffle"
